# OAT++ installation failed on centos 7

Tags: oat++

I tried install OAT++. But failed.

os information

```
[root@localhost build]# cat /etc/*-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

How to resolve below error?

```
[ 84%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/oatppAllTests.dir/oatpp/core/data/share/StringTemplateTest.cpp.o
/home/happyteam/jjumdong/oatpp/test/oatpp/core/data/share/StringTemplateTest.cpp: In member function 'virtual void oatpp::test::core::data::share::StringTemplateTest::onRun()':
/home/happyteam/jjumdong/oatpp/test/oatpp/core/data/share/StringTemplateTest.cpp:38:52: error: call of overloaded 'format(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
     auto result = t.format({oatpp::String("Hello")});
                                                    ^
/home/happyteam/jjumdong/oatpp/test/oatpp/core/data/share/StringTemplateTest.cpp:38:52: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/happyteam/jjumdong/oatpp/test/oatpp/core/data/share/StringTemplateTest.cpp:27:0:
/home/happyteam/jjumdong/oatpp/src/oatpp/core/data/share/StringTemplate.hpp:175:17: note: oatpp::String oatpp::data::share::StringTemplate::format(const std::vector<oatpp::data::mapping::type::String>&) const
   oatpp::String format(const std::vector<oatpp::String>& params) const;
                 ^
/home/happyteam/jjumdong/oatpp/src/oatpp/core/data/share/StringTemplate.hpp:189:17: note: oatpp::String oatpp::data::share::StringTemplate::format(const String&) const
   oatpp::String format(const oatpp::String& singleValue) const;
                 ^
```

I succeed OAT++ installation on ubuntu.

Why failed to OAT++ installation on centos 7?

Answer (score 2):

You have failing tests, not the oatpp library itself.
Just disable tests by adding `-DOATPP_BUILD_TESTS=OFF` cmake flag and rebuild:

```
cmake -DOATPP_BUILD_TESTS=OFF ..
make install
```

---

**To fix tests:**

In file `oatpp/test/oatpp/core/data/share/StringTemplateTest` change
all occurrences of similar code:

```
auto result = t.format({oatpp::String("Hello")});
```

to

```
auto result = t.format(std::vector<oatpp::String>({"Hello"}));
```

**If you fix tests, please send a PR!**